# OS X Bash scripting

Tags: regex, macos, bash, shell

I don't do much shell scripting, but I want to essentially do this:

1. run the command "grunt check" about 30 times (the process takes 60 seconds).
2. Do a regex on the output of that command for "Some random error message. Failed." Where "Failed" is the thing I'm searching for but I want to capture the whole sentence.
3. Write the associated line to a file.

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   COUNTER=0
   while [  $COUNTER -lt 30 ]; do
       command grunt check
       // ERROR = regex(/\/Failed./)
       // WRITE ERROR TO FILE
       let COUNTER=COUNTER+1
   done
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
counter=0
while [  $counter -lt 30 ]; do
    grunt check | grep Failed
    let counter=counter+1 
done > some file
```

The above uses a pipeline to capture the output of the `grunt` command and sent it to `grep`.  `grep` searches through the output and prints any lines that contain the word `Failed`.  Any such lines are then sent to a file named `somefile`.

As a minor point, I have converted COUNTER to lower case.  This is because the system uses upper case environment variables.  If you make a practice of using lower case ones then you won't accidentally overwrite one.  (In this particular case, there is no system variable named COUNTER, so you are safe.)

#### Another method for counting to 30:

You might find this simpler:

```
for counter in {1..30}; do
    grunt check | grep Failed
done > somefile
```

The `{1..30}` notation provides the numbers from one to thirty.  It is a bash feature so don't try to use it on a bare-bones POSIX shell.

#### To get more context

If you would like to see more context around the error message, `grep` offers several options to help.  To see both the line matching "Failed" and the line before, use `-B`:

```
for counter in {1..30}; do
    grunt check | grep -B 1 Failed
done >somefile
```

Similarly, `-A` can be used to display lines after the match.  `-C` will display lines both before and after the match.

Comment: It just seems weird to use 1-30 when OP used 0-29, even though it doesnt really matter.

Comment: @StevenPenny Yes, computer scientists do like to start counting at zero.  So, as you prefer, `{1..30}` can be replaced with `{0..29}`.

Comment: Na, dont change it on my account

Comment: this is great. Can I get the line that contains "Failed." and the line above it?

Comment: Add `-B 1` after grep:
`grunt check | grep -B 1 Failed >somefile`

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek I added that to the answer.

Comment: this works perfectly. Now how do I check for multiple words. This did not work: grunt check | grep -B 1 Failed|Done|Aborted - I tried with quotes also.

Comment: @Jeff Add the `-E` option to get extended regex: `grunt check | grep -EB 1 'Failed|Done|Aborted'`

Answer (score 2):

```
for ((cr=0; cr<30; cr++))
do
   grunt check | grep Failed
done > outfile.txt
```